# Passing parameter from route to controller in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to pass a variable from route to controller. But not able to succeed.

my route entry is as below

```
Route::get('/Register', 'NewRegister@CheckCand');
```

now in the controller file I want to get one parameter. My controller function is as below

```
public function CheckCand()
{
    echo $ID;
}
```

Now how do I pass a variable ID from route to controller. But i don't want to pass it in the URL and also in get function i dont want to change '/Register'.

Route::get('/Register', 'NewRegister@CheckCand');

Means it will be like a Hidden parameter passed from route to controller. 
Might be question is confusing but i don't know how to explain better.

Comment: It's a GET route, therefore all route parameters should be passed in the URL

Comment: ok. But is there any other method by which i can pass parameter from route to controller. When i click a link on a web page it will go to route and from route it will call a controller with parameter not defined in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Pass as request parameter and retrieve it in the controller using request. Something like below.

**jQuery**

```
$.get('/register', {ID :'123'}, function(data) {});
```

or

**Javascript**

```
<a href="{{ url('register') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('register-form').submit();">...</a>
<form id="register-form" action="{{ url('register') }}" method="GET" style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="ID" value="..."/></form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function CheckCand(Request $request) {
    $request->ID;
}
```

Comment: I am calling the CheckCand() function on a hyperlink click. So how should i call this jquery in route file.

Comment: Try adding the id as parameter to the url. Like `href="/register?ID=123"`

Comment: that is what i was asking. I don't want to pass parameter in URL.

Comment: @Kash Sorry forgot the original question. You can't write jquery call in `route` file. It's a front end. I updated the question to include javascript way. Check if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the parameters by `Request` so in your function request the parameters as you named when you passed them

```
public function CheckCand(){

$request = Request::all();
$ID = $request->ID ;
// Or
$ID = $request['ID'];
}
```

Comment: requesting the parameter is fine but how to pass from route to controller.

Comment: You pass them through your JS code as `Parameters`  with `Key` s and `Value` s so you don't have to add the within your `route` files @Kash